# Dynamically generated dropdown list breaks web service call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an ASPX dropdown list, that is used in a web service call to generate a graph.

If I manually enter the drop down list entries, the code executes fine, however if I dynamically generate the dropdown list from the SQL server the web service call fails.

Here is how I am generating the dropdown list:

```
//Populate Customers DDL

string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Indigo2.Properties.Settings.ConstrNW"].ConnectionString;
DataTable customers = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT custid from [Indigo].[dbo].[invoices] WHERE custid='ACC001'", con);
                    adapter.Fill(customers);
                    //ddlCustA.DataSource = customers;
                    //ddlCustA.DataTextField = "custid";
                    //ddlCustA.DataValueField = "custid";
                    //ddlCustA.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle the error
                }

    }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustA" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="100px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This is where I call the Web Service

```
    //Code for graph (all in document ready)
    $("#btn_line_chart").on('click', function () {
        var CustA = $("#ddlCustA").val();
        var CustB = $("#ddlCustB").val();
        var getYear = $("#ddlYear").val();

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            custA: CustA,
            custB: CustB,
            year: getYear
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService1.asmx/getLineChartData",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess_,
            error: OnErrorCall_
        });

        function OnSuccess_(reponse) {
            var aData = reponse.d;
            var aLabels = aData[0];
            var aDatasets1 = aData[1];
            var aDatasets2 = aData[2];

            var data = {
                labels: aLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: aDatasets1
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: aDatasets2
                }]
            };

            var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext('2d');
            ctx.canvas.width = 750; // setting width of canvas
            ctx.canvas.height = 400;  // setting height of canvas

            var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "line",
                data: data,
                bezierCurve: false
            });
        }
        function OnErrorCall_(repo) {
            alert("Woops something went wrong, pls try later !");
        }
    });
```

If I manually choose the dropdown list options (like below), it works fine.

```
    <select id="ddlCustA">
        <option>ACC001</option>
    </select>
```

When the dropdown list is generated from the SQL server, the web service call fails with the folowing error:

> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition
>   that prevented it from fulfilling the request. (XHR)POST -
>   https://localhost:44338/WebService1.asmx/getLineChartData

Any help greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: It seems to be a timing issue. If I add an alert just before the web service calls the ddlCustA variable, ddlCustA shows as "Undefined"

```
alert($("#ddlCustA").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else, my solution was the way I was calling the object from Javasctipt. The below code fixed it.

```
 var CustA = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCustA.ClientID %>').value
```